# Jython Pip module is not available

Tags: ubuntu, jython

How does one install pip ? The 'ensurepip' is not shipped by default?

```
 $ jython -m ensurepip
/usr/share/jython/bin/jython: No module named ensurepip

$ jython -m pip install
/usr/share/jython/bin/jython: No module named pip
```

Using package from Impish Jython version: 2.7.2

```
jython:
  Installed: 2.7.2+repack1-3
  Candidate: 2.7.2+repack1-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.2+repack1-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

Answer (score 0):

The ensurepip command is run only once during the installation of the package.

The solution is to use the latest installer from Jython.org if you want to use pip.